# Could not parse the remainder: '{{ list[loop.index0] }}'

Tags: python, html, django, templates, jinja2

I followed instructions in simmilar thread like: [How do you index on a jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233721/how-do-you-index-on-a-jinja-template)

but my html template is not working and whole django project is not responding due to this.

Error that I'm getting:

> Error during template rendering.
>
> Could not parse the remainder: '[loop.index0]' from 'songs_titles[loop.index0]'

My code looks like this:

```
{% if converted_files_urls %}
    <p>Titles: {{ songs_titles }}</p>
    {% for n in converted_files_urls %}
        <a href="{{ n }}" download>Download:  {{ songs_titles[loop.index0] }}</a>
        <br/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

and the {{ songs_titles }} renders as list, so at least till here it works ok.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not using Jinja. This is Django template language.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are looking for Jinja, that will not work on django.

In django template tag you should use `forloop.counter0` and list indexing looks like

`{{songs_titles.1}}`

Need to set count in variable and then use it, for setting variable you could use -

```
{% with index=forloop.counter0 %}     

   {{ songs_titles.index}}

{% endwith %}
```

Still If you have any doubts you can comment it.

Comment: {{ songs_titles.1 }} works, and {{ forloop.counter0 }} shows 0, 1, 3, 4 and so on, but
{{ songs_titles.forloop.counter0 }} doesn't show anything

Comment: Your solutions renders error :/ 
Error during template rendering.
'with' expected at least one variable assignment

Comment: Remove before and after space of "=", see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this by creating a custom template tag like here: 
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2740/

But to be honest it sucks that that's the simplest working solution for now :/