# Need to run 2 Loops in the same statement in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-bootstrap

This is the
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulGqx.png)
that I am getting. I need it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoGJI.png).
This is the code I'm using to show the "bunkable" value but I'm not getting proper output. Bunkable is a list and the datas is a list of tuples from SQLite. Any suggestions on how I can fix this or do I need to give more context/information?

```
        <div class='table-responsive-sm'>
      <table class='table table-bordered table-striped '>
        <thead style="background-color: #007ac6; color:aliceblue;" class="text-center">
          <th>CourseID</th>
          <th>Subject</th>
          <th>Bunked</th>
          <th>Remaining Hours</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for row in datas%}
            <tr>
              <td>{{row.CourseID}}</td>
              <td>{{row.Subject}}</td>
              <td>{{row.bunkedHours}}</td>
          {% endfor %}
          {% for bunkable in bunk %}
              <td>{{bunkable}}</td>
            </tr>
          {%endfor%}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try putting your tables in a markdown format or as in line code. Linking them to images is not ideal

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but could you do something like this

```
{% for row in datas%}
       <tr>
         <td>{{row.CourseID}}</td>
         <td>{{row.Subject}}</td>
         <td>{{row.bunkedHours}}</td>
         <td>{{bunk[loop.index0]}}</td>
       </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233721/how-do-you-index-on-a-jinja-template) related question, but it should work by getting the same index from the bunk list, which seems to be what you need to do.

So give that a try and let me know, as long as they are the same length lists always I think it should. Sorry if I am missing something, because I haven't had time to reproduce it and try this yet.